# Numpy cannot broadcast array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, anaconda

I am writing code to mimic Conway's game of life (10 cell line). I am almost done but my code is giving me the error

```
could not broadcast array from shape (7,11) into shape (10)
```

Here is the code that I believe is where the problem is.

```
glider = np.zeros([7,11])
glider[3,:]=1
glider[(3,0)]=0
glider[(3,10)]=0
N=(10) # the domain is NxN, N=10 for testing, more interesting with N=100
init_choice = 1 # 0 for random initialization
c = np.random.choice( (1,0), N*N, p=[0.3,0.7] ).reshape(N,N) # default initialization is random
if init_choice == 1:
    c = c*0
    c[3,:] = glider # put glider in top left
if init_choice == 2:
    print("not implemented yet")

periodic(c)
```

which gives the result

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-53-0a8812bfb2f8> in <module>()
      4 if init_choice == 1:
      5     c = c*0
      6     c[3,:] = glider # put glider in top left
      7 if init_choice == 2:
      8     print("not implemented yet")

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (7,11) into shape (10)
```

Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUb6h.png).

Answer (score 0):

The shapes of `c` and `glider` don't match.  Try it interactively.  One is 10x10, the other 7x11.

In 1d copying one array into another (larger) involves something like:

```
A = np.zeros(10)
B = np.ones(2)
A[3:5] = B
```

Comment: I guess I don't know where to change the size of c

Comment: This is a basic numpy indexing problem that you need to work out for yourself.  How to put a glider of any shape in a same shaped subset of cells in `c`.  Start small - 1 cell, 2, 2x2 etc.